# Haaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Last year, we had the [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh) on Physics Stack Exchange.

For those who weren't around or don't remember, the event is one where completing various achievements on the site earns you different hats that can be "worn" on site; appearing on top of your gravatar wherever it is shown on the site. They're basically badges that you can wear.

We need to let the team know whether or not we want to participate as a site this year. So, what say?

Note that individuals can opt out if they wish.

Update: Given the response, I've submitted the form for enabling it on our site. Those who didn't want hats, let us know if you are having trouble disabling it (note: it's only going to be around for the last week of December). Those who want hats, here's something to satiate your hunger for hats until the Winter Bash:

[image]

Comment: I hope there will be an actual Mexican Hat Potential Hat among the available hats!

Comment: @Nathaniel I doubt it, but there is a chance. Last year there was talk of custom per-site hats.

Comment: Egad!  it's the Physics Sombrero!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MmIoN.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/aM4ik.png

Answer (score 24):

Haaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaats!

(In other words, upvote this if you want hats)

Comment: I want a cowboy-ninja-fireman-astronaut-pirate hat. With a bobble on top.

Comment: I've always wanted a propellor beanie. We don't have them in the UK, and how can I be a real nerd without a propellor beanie?

Comment: @JohnRennie There was one last year I think, and it was pretty easy to get, too :D

Comment: It took me about 2 minutes of staring at the two answers to figure out that this was a poll. Hats sound fun.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Physics.SE as a whole should participate in this event.

Comment: I almost downvoted this answer but realised I'd be reducing Manish's reputation. Even though I doubt Manish would care about (or even notice) the -2 rep hit it still seems a bit harsh :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie Psh. I wouldn't notice/care, also, you forgot that meta posts don't affect rep except on the mother meta.

Comment: @JohnRennie: There's no rep for meta.

Comment: @DIMension10 yup, except [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). Which acts as individual site.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: [mso] isn't exactly a meta site for [so]. It is the meta for [se] in general, so I wouldn't count that as a "meta" of the same sense. Hm... what's the short form for meta stack overflow again? .